# Do we need guru for doing meditation which is mentioned in Bhagavad Geeta chapter 6?

Tags: bhagavad-gita, guru, meditation

There are so many forms and types of meditation techniques. I don't know if all those are the same or different.

So just to start something I want to try the meditation technique given in Bhagavad Geeta in chapter 6.

Do we need a guru for doing meditation which is mentioned in Bhagavad Geeta chapter 6?

Comment: Only a disciplined/purified mind, that had transcended worldly possessions , enjoyments can remain steady in meditation.In BG 3.6 , Lord demeans, those who outwardly restrain their external organs and sit in meditation pose as Mithyacharaha , Vimudathma (hypocrite) . Instead BG 3.7 recommends engaging in dharmic action by restraining the mind , (rather than mere restraint of external organ) is way superior for a beginner.

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of resources available for learning meditations including online videos and books. You can start with that. You will be able to learn all the basics by following such resources. However, when it will come to advance studies, you will need someone who have done it right and achieved the results. Finding such gurus is difficult. Be careful about the gurus that are trying to get popularity and money.

Meditation is not like a physical exercise. It is related to your mind. Becoming a good human being is very important to get success in meditation. Hence, Maharshi Patanjali prescribe Yama and Niyama as the first 2 steps out of total 8 steps.

Common misconception is that meditation will give you mental peace etc. However, if you become a good human being you will get mental peace and that will make you eligible to progress on the path of meditation. For all these you do not need a Guru.

Here is short description of Yama and Niyama: https://www.ekhartyoga.com/articles/philosophy/the-yamas-and-niyamas

Wish you all the best in your endeavor.